# Proceed after zero rows inserted (PL/SQL, Oracle)

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, oracle12c

I have below insert running into pl/sql code:

```
PROCEDURE insertA(param in varchar2)
IS                
    v_col VARCHAR2(32000) := 'colA, colB, colC';
     v_ins    VARCHAR2(32000) := 'INSERT INTO '||getU||'.'||My_TABLE||' ('||v_col||') '
                   || '(SELECT 'A',
                valueB as B,
                             valueC as C
                    from table2
                        where colX = '''||param||''');

BEGIN       
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_ins; 
END;
```

But when `select 'A', valueB, valueC from table2` is 0 then I got error like:

ORA-01403 No data was found from the objects.

**How to proceed anyway?**

Or just skip the insert, as this insertA is executed from WPF by C#.

Comment: Your requirement is, *if the insert fails because there's no data just ignore the error and carry on*??? Why bother with the insert at all, if you don't care whether it succeeds or fails?

Comment: can you show how to do that?

Comment: AFAIK, `insert ... select ...` doesn't raise `NO_DATA_FOUND`.

Comment: @BobJarvis I don't see any sub-select, other than the one that's part of `insert ... select`, which won't give a `no_data_found` exception. There is clearly a whole bunch of code missing here. Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @AdrianNicolae's suggestion, rewrite your procedure as:

```
PROCEDURE insertA(param in varchar2)
IS                
    v_col VARCHAR2(32000) := 'colA, colB, colC';
     v_ins    VARCHAR2(32000) := 'INSERT INTO '||getU||'.'||My_TABLE||' ('||v_col||') '
                   || '(SELECT 'A',
                valueB as B,
                             valueC as C
                    from table2
                        where colX = '''||param||''');

BEGIN       
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_ins;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
```

We're just adding an exception handler for the NO_DATA_FOUND (ORA-1403) exception, which in this case catches the exception but doesn't do anything with it, in effect allowing the code to proceed onwards when this exception is encountered.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Exception when data is not found.

```
EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
```

I'm new in PL/SQL so i can't help too much but really hope this will help you.

Comment: That will not help. EXCEPTION will take you to the end of the PL/SQL block, you can't return from there to "normal" execution. You **could** use EXCEPTION (indeed, that is the preferred method), but you need to put the code for the insert AND the exception within its own block, so if EXCEPTION is encountered, then it is handled and then control is passed back to the main block.